# pass the URL to multiple non-activity java class android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, xml-parsing, uri

In both the activity I am passing this URL http://example.com/ss.svc/APIabc?A=10&Key=XXXXX&From=19&To=221&Date=19-Apr-2016  ,but the thing is I am passing some dynamic parameters to the link which I passed to   **CustomizedListView.java** activity  and that same dynamic  link I want to pass to **XMLParser.java** ,which I am unable to pass....at present I pasted the static link in the **XMLParser.java** but in that I want to get the link which is being passed dynamically in the **CustomizedListView.java** activity.

**I did like this in CustomizedListView.java**

```
Intent i4 = new Intent(this, XMLParser.class);
        i4.putExtra("epuzzle", URL);
         Log.d("URLURLURLURLURL ", "> " + URL);
        startActivity(i4);
```

**And I did like this in XMLParser.java**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String easyPuzzle = intent.getExtras().getString("epuzzle");
```

**CustomizedListView.java**

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
        // All static variables
        static final String URL = "http://example.com/ss.svc/APIabc?A=10&Key=XXXXX&From=19&To=221&Date=19-Apr-2016";
        // XML node keys 
        static final String KEY_SONG = "Route"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "Avail";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "Avail";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "Avail";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST2 = "Avail";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "Avail";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

        ListView list;
        LazyAdapter adapter;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt; songsList = new ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt;();

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
            // looping through all song nodes &lt;song&gt;
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap&lt;String, String&gt; map = new HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key =&gt; value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
                map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                songsList.add(map);
            }

            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

            // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Click event for single list row
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView&lt;?&gt; parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**XMLParser.java**

```
public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

           // InputSource is = new InputSource();
             //   is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse("http://example.com/ss.svc/APIabc?A=10&Key=XXXXX&From=19&To=221&Date=19-Apr-2016"); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }
}
```

**Earlier my problem was** [Earlier Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734137/xml-parser-unexpected-token-error-positiontext-12-in-java-io-stringreader?noredirect=1#comment61051906_36734137) **so I passed the static link then it worked perfectly ....and now the problem came up to make the dynamically generated link to be same in both the Java files.**

Comment: in your code `XMLParser` is not an `Activity`, right?

Comment: yaa you are right its not an activity

Comment: `XMLParser` is not a `Activity`, why you use `Intent` to `startActivity`

Comment: @PhanVănLinh actually my friend my problem was this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734137/xml-parser-unexpected-token-error-positiontext-12-in-java-io-stringreader?noredirect=1#comment61051906_36734137 so i passed the static link then it worked perfectly ....and now the problem came up to make the dynamically generated link to be same in both the java files.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh any idea ?

Comment: sorry, I don't have any idea. I never use the `Intent` to start a `Java class` that is not an `Activity`

Comment: @PhanVănLinh yaa i got the solution after searching.I am posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got the solution actually I the way to do is to pass the value from the activity class to the non-activity class.**

**So, I received the value to XMLParser.java like this below**

```
     public Document getDomElement(String xml){
            Document doc = null;
<-------------LIKE THIS--------------------------->
            String var = CustomizedListView.URL;
<---------------------------------------->
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {

                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

                //InputSource is = new InputSource();
                  //  is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                    doc = db.parse(var);
```

**Do upvote if it helped you.**